# Codeigniter ajax input file gather value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i've trying to see some examples before but in ajax when we use form-data we need to serialize it individualy? because i serialize the normal data and its fine, but the input file type i cant pass by post his value, but if i print the value it shows correctly but in data with his name reference is not working.

My form example code :

```
<form id="Add-Form" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label-control col-md-2"> tt </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="file" id="sd"  name="s" class="btn btn-default" ></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the ajax part.

```
var url = $('#Add-Modal').attr('action');
var data = $('#Add-Form').serialize();

var title = $('input[name=title]');
var body = $('textarea[name=subject]');
var file = $('input[name=s]');

$.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: instead of getting field individually use this: `var data = $(this).serialize()` on form submit

Comment: yes but i used in this way to get individualy for validate the fields :)

Answer (score 0):

Upload image using ajax:

Try this way

```
<form id="Add-Form" action="Your controller method name(Example:<?=base_url().'Test_controller/test_image'?>)" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="label-control col-md-2"> tt </label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="file" id="sd"  name="s" class="btn btn-default" ></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Add-Form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($("#Add-Form")[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url : $("#Add-Form").attr('action'),
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'POST',
                data : formData,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);                    
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
function test_image() {
  print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i have a normal form with information, i dont wanna only pass the information of the image name, i wanna pass the image name/file and the other but idk if there is a cast of it. Your way will make the things different

Comment: btw with this way how do you handle form data after append, i mean how do i choose the file that im receiving because if i console.log the formdata it doesnt show the objects, its blank

Comment: Formdata is object type and send data with encoded format so you can not print data in console.but you can print data in your controller function.
and FormData post all data to controller function available between form tag. so as per your first comment my answer is formdata  send any type of data whatever you want.@Enigma

Comment: yes it does, but i had to read few docs because i was sending data and formData but when i handle at controller, my ajax moves allways to error without print or console log anything

Comment: The code is equal i just deleted the normal data and send everything via formData but the $_FILES is not working yet when i handle